# Password control updated in the background does not reflect in the UI in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have an ASP.NET web application where I want to customize the createUser wizard.
In the user registration workflow, instead of asking the users to enter password, I am generating the password programmatically and assign it the password control when it is being loaded. This control will be disabled and sent as a notification to the user. The following snippets are .aspx and corresponding C# code.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password" OnLoad="GenerateRandomPassword" />


protected void GenerateRandomPassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox pwdTextBox = (TextBox)RegisterUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password");

        if (pwdTextBox != null)
        {
            pwdTextBox.Text = Membership.GeneratePassword(8, 2);                
        }
    }
```

I have debugged the code, I can see that the text property of password text box is set properly, but it is not updated in the UI. Is there anything else I need to do?
Can any one tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Where you calling `GenerateRandomPassword` function

Comment: In OnLoad of Password control. You can see it in the code snippet by scrolling right.

Comment: I think instead of calling it in OnLoad of control, you call it in Page_Load event

Comment: I tried that also. I faced the same issue

Comment: Are you using any update panel ??

Comment: What is update panel?

Comment: Why are you setting TextMode="Password"? The point of that is to hide the characters that are typed, but if you're generating them yourself why even bother just showing a TextBox with asterisks in it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set value for password inputs:

```
pwdTextBox.Attributes.Add("value", Membership.GeneratePassword(8, 2));
```